# How to disable auto-rotation for specific View Controllers inside a Navigation Controller (Swift)?

Tags: xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

^Above does not have answer at all...Having issues disabling auto rotation for specific (not all) View Controllers that are inside a navigation controller. Similar questions do not address the ability to disable autorotation for specific view controllers but rather to disable autorotation in all of the view controllers inside of a navigation controller. My navigation controller contains some VCs that I would like to have autorotation and others that I do not want to autorotate. No existing questions answer this satisfactorily.

Comment: The answer suggested does not offer swift code and any similar questions do not provide working code for the new version of swift.

Comment: Adding `shouldAutorotate()` to the `navigationController` instead of the `viewController` fixed it for me. Make sure to assign a class to the `navigationController`. I can elaborate if you want me to.

Comment: I have an idea of what you are referring to but would greatly appreciate if you could elaborate...thanks in advance @StevoHN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made an example project on how to do this: [GitHub repo](https://github.com/zzzel/DontRotateSwift).

While @Sidetalker's answer is correct I think it lacks a bit of explanation.

Basically you create a Custom Class for your `UINavigationController` and assign it to `UINavigationController` in Storyboard. In the custom `UINavigationController` class you `override` the `shouldAutorotate` function and check if the `topViewController` is `ViewController`(the class of your `UIViewController` in Storyboard) of the class on which you want to disable autorotate.

In custom `UINavigationController`:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
if !viewControllers.isEmpty {

  // Check if this ViewController is the one you want to disable roration on
  if topViewController!.isKindOfClass(ViewController) {

    // If true return false to disable it
    return false
  }
}

// Else normal rotation enabled
return true
}
```

Comment: very helpful and completely does what I wanted.

Comment: @zzzel.. I am programatically adding the uinavigationcontroller and its view controller however its rotating the view...no not working!!!

Comment: @Saty That's a different example than. Open a new SO Question.